# V brakes either too weak or rub

Tags: brakes

I have just bought a used bike and the brakes were able to be pulled all the way to the handle.

However if I try tightening them even slightly they will rub against the wheels.

How do you fix this?

Comment: First I would check the cables and see if they're frayed.  Then look at the pads -- likely they are badly worn.

Comment: A photo might help - could be a mismatch between lever pull and brake type.  Are your wheels true ?  Could even be old brake pads simply being hardened.

Answer (score 7):

One problem that leads to this exact symptom is if someone installed V-brakes along with cantilever/caliper brake levers, or in the case of a multi-setting brake lever, has it set to the "short pull" mode.

You can get more detail on how to tell the difference from [this question.](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20809/what-is-the-actual-cable-pull-of-brake-levers)

If it's an incompatibility between levers and brakes, it's usually going to be cheaper parts-wise to replace the levers. There's not really another fix.

Comment: The other possible cause is a wobbly wheel. Fix would be truing the wheel.