# Problem tensioning brake lever cable

Tags: brakes

Good morning everyone,
I have a problem with adjusting mechanical disc brakes, especially the avid bb7's,
I have adjusted the caliper position, the position of the pads and connected the cable to the piston without any problem so there is no rubbing between the pads and the disc.  I attach photos
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AKCYMQeDqgcYcEl4YDgcxuunYS9NdVd0/view?usp=drivesdk

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AUFj6Iv6VXqyXKv4_q6ALE-9wyOtPWha/view?usp=drivesdk

The problem I'm having is that when braking the disc doesn't lock effectively and the brake lever ends up touching the handlebar.
I have a bike with drop handlebars and the brake levers don't have barrel adjuster so to solve the problem I tried:

- pull the cable as far as possible and fix it higher up in the brake piston, but this doesn't solve the problem because pulling too much causes the wheel to get blocked and pulling less does not get the desired effect.
- adjust the position of the pads, but this also does not solve.
  I really don't know what to do anymore so I ask you for help, I specify that the cables are new, I don't know if this can affect their behavior, thanks to all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cable pull is wrong. Brakes come in 'Long pull' - most common on MTB and 'Short pull' - most common on road bike - to the extent they are often considered synonymous.  The BB7's you have are long pull (Labeled BB7_MTB). They come in a short pull version, labeled BB7-Road which is the model you need for drop bar shifters.

Have a read of [What is the actual cable pull of brake levers?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20809/what-is-the-actual-cable-pull-of-brake-levers)