Is a given cable disk brake caliper compatible with any cable disk brake lever?
I am looking to replace Tektro mechanical disk brakes on a gravel bike with drop bars. These brakes are Norco's factory brakes and the levers are Shimano Tiagra. The calipers should be one of these (https://tektro.com/en/category/8), but the brakes have nothing printed on them.
I was assuming that any cable disk brake caliper for the same rotor size would do, but I got confused by brake descriptions such as "Compatibility: Mountain style levers" ("SRAM Avid BB5 Cable Disc Brake Caliper With 160mm Rotor"). Hence my question, do I have to look for cable disk brake calipers that are compatible with drop bar levers, or will any fitting disk brake caliper do?
Another example is for the "Shimano Tourney TX805 Mechanical Disc Brake Calliper", which mentions "Recommended brake lever: V-BRAKE BL(1.5-2.5 finger)".

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20809/what-is-the-actual-cable-pull-of-brake-levers Should go some way to explaining the two usual standards frequently split into "MTB" and "Road".

Thanks! That helps. In short, the answer is 'No'.

Wait, mechanical or hydraulic? GRX is hydraulic only, the levers cannot use mechanical (cable) brakes.

@VladimirFГероямслава : valid point! The group set is GRX. The actual levers are Tiagra it seems. I have updated the question.

@Steven You need "Road" calipers, anything for V-brake levers is unsuitable. Look at Avid BB5r and BB7r, then TRP Spyre for mainstream examples.
